# How do I decrypt a PEM private key in python

Tags: openssl, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric, python-3.9

OK, so i've found a way to encrypt private keys when exporting them to PEM bytes, something like this (all the code is from Nitratine and StackOverflow (who would've guessed)) for a new module called encrypterlib

```
def generate_private_bytes_from_key(key: _RSAPrivateKey, password: bytes = None):
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
    return key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(password) if type(password) == bytes else serialization.NoEncryption()
        )
```

**but I can't decrypt it:**

Python console:

```
Python 3.9.1 and some other text
>>> from encrypterlib import *
>>> private_key = asymmetric.generate_key()
>>> private_bytes = asymmetric.generate_private_bytes_from_key(private_key, password = b"p@ssw0rd")
>>> private_key_2 = asymmetric.generate_key_from_private_bytes(private_bytes, password = b"p@ssw0rd")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\encrypterlib.py", line 30, in generate_key_from_private_bytes
    return serialization.load_pem_private_key(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\base.py", line 18, in load_pem_private_key
    return backend.load_pem_private_key(data, password)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 1244, in load_pem_private_key
    return self._load_key(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 1465, in _load_key
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Password was not given but private key is encrypted
>>>
```

The module:

```
def generate_key_from_private_bytes(bytes: bytes, password: bytes = None):
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
    return serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        bytes,
        password=password if type(password) == bytes else None,
        backend=default_backend()
        )
```

But Cryptography doesn't acknowledge the fact that I provided a password. Any help?

Comment: It is a **bad idea** to name an argument with same name as a type, in this case `bytes`. My guess is that `if type(password) == bytes...` is not doing what you expect because of this.

Comment: Decryption works on my machine after fixing the bug identified by President James K. Polk.

Comment: Thanks, so the problem was my Code was I replaced a builtin :/

Comment: Just a small note: there is not a single PEM private key encoding. Private keys first are encoded in some standardized format. However, that encoding may then be wrapped by PKCS#8 inner structure, which may be encrypted and put in a PKCS#8 outer structure. All this is usually encoded using ASN.1 BER/DER encoding. Finally, that structure may be PEM encoded (making it text, i.e. an ASCII armor). To top it off, PEM also can indicate the encryption technique. You can see this because there are, for example,  "RSA PRIVATE KEY" and just "PRIVATE KEY" PEM files.